# Can't load my custom library codeigniter 3.0

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am a newbie of codeigniter.
in codeigniter v3.0, I try to load my custom library. but it seem not work.

This is my source code.

**Library**

```
class MY_Login extends CI_Controller{

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        // call with constructor.
        $this->isLogin();
    }

    function isLogin() {
         //source code
    }  
}
```

**Controller**

```
class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {

    protected $CI;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library("MY_Login");
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: where you put My_Login controller?

Comment: @Decode you need execute code inside `isLogin()` By Default??

Comment: yes. every controller except login page..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A codeigniter library file goes in application > libraries > My_login.php you do not need extend CI_Controller just class

```
class My_login {

    function __construct() {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();

        $this->isLogin();
    }

    function isLogin() {
         //source code
    }  
}
```

Controller

```
class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library("my_login");

}
}
```

When you use MY_Controller in application > core

```
<?php

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
}

}
```

Controller extending core MY_Controller

```
class Dashboard extends MY_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library("my_login");

}
}
```

Comment: I solved it. You saved my time now ^^. thanks buddy.

Answer (score 0):

Place **MY_Login** Controller in Core folder. then,

```
class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {

protected $CI;

  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->CI =& get_instance();
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Library you don't need to extend CI_Controller. Just write the class name. Place this file in `application/libraries`

```
class MY_Login{
  protected $CI;
  function __construct() {
       // call with constructor.
      $this->isLogin();
  }

  function isLogin() {
     //source code
  }  
}
```

Now for controller `Dashboard.php`

```
class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library("MY_Login");
    }
}
```

This will work fine. Please try it.

Comment: parent:: __construct(); can't use when we didn't extend CI_controller